# 12V -> 110V@0.11A DC/DC. what topology?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I need to design a step-up converter with following specs:

vin = 12V +/- 10%
vout = 110V
iout = 0.11A
non-isolated

The most problematic constraint is that the converter must be very compact. Component height is limited to 10mm or thereabouts and PCB space roughly 25mm x 45mm.

Designing such a converter would otherwise be a moderately complex task, but I'm wondering how to reduce the physical size. Multiplied boost and full-bridge forward come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

How much ripple can you accept on the output? I don't think the full-bridge would be the best option, simply due to the number of components. You can get the LC components pretty small by using a higher switching frequency and polymer electrolytic caps however. Of course, the gate charge of the switching MOSFET becomes more critical at higher frequencies. Any idea what you'd use to drive it? The MOSFET would have to be mounted to some sort of heat sink, perhaps bolted to the device.

Here are some useful links to explore, from simple to advanced:

- [Adafruit DIY Boost Calculator](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-boost-calc/the-calculator)
- [TI WebBench Software](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/power.page)
- [PowerEsim Software](http://www.poweresim.com/)